# Método do controller recebendo valor errado no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Um pedaço da minha aplicação, consiste no cliente logar e a partir daí cadastrar algumas informações pertinentes diariamente. Ao logar, ele cai na tela para escolher em qual captação ele irá cadastrar os dados. Na próxima ele escolhe qual sistema de captação, e por fim, ele insere os dados.  Para isso tenho as seguintes rotas:

```
Route::get('/prop/{id_prop}/', 'PropriedadeController@clientePropriedade');
Route::get('/prop/{id_prop}/cap/{id_cap}/', 'CaptacaoController@clienteCaptacao')->name('cap');
Route::get('/prop/{id_prop}/cap/{id_cap}/sis/{id_sis}/', 'SistemaController@clienteSistema')->name('sis');
```

Meu problema é: quando clico no link para alguma captação, sempre sou direcionado para a página do Sistema de Captação pertencente a captação 1. Independente da captação que eu escolher, sempre sou direcionado para o sistema da captação 1. Usando o método dd() do Laravel para debugar, percebi que o parâmetro (int id) de meu método clienteCaptacao de CaptacaoController tem valor 1.

```
 public function clienteCaptacao(int $id)
 {
    dd($id);//valor 1
    $cap = Captacao::find($id);

    //dd($cap);
    if (!isset($cap)) {
        return view('erros.cliente.nCadastrado',
            array('nome' => 'captações'));
    } else {
        return view('cliente.escolheSistema', compact('cap'));
    }
 }
```

Os links estão corretos:

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <a href=http://h20.laravel/cliente/prop/1/cap/1 
        class="btn  btn-secondary btn-block" style="background-color:red">Captacao 1</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <a href=http://h20.laravel/cliente/prop/1/cap/2 
        class="btn  btn-secondary btn-block" style="background-color:red">Captacao 2</a>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <a href=http://h20.laravel/cliente/prop/1/cap/3 
        class="btn  btn-secondary btn-block" style="background-color:red">Captacao 3</a>
 </div>
```

Esses são os códigos da minha blade onde crio os links acima:

```
<div class="row">
   @foreach ($prop->captacoes as $cap)
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
        <a href={{
           URL::route("cap",
            ['id_prop'=>$prop->id, 'id_cap'=>$cap->id])}} 
                class="btn  btn-secondary btn-block" style="background-color:red">{{$cap->nome}}</a>
    </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como sua rota contem dois parâmetros, é o primeiro parâmetro que está sendo injetado em seu método, no caso, `{id_prop}`.
Veja a descrição presente no site do laravel

> Route parameters are injected into route callbacks / controllers based
>   on their order - the names of the callback / controller arguments do
>   not matter.
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters

Para resolver seu problema, seu método `clienteCaptacao` deve receber dois parâmetros, um será o `id_prop` e o outro o `id_cap`.

Answer (score 1):

Isso está acontecendo porque você está recebendo dois parâmetros de id na sua rota, e ai ele está pegando apenas o primeiro

```
href=http://h20.laravel/cliente/prop/1/cap/1
```

Qual a versão do laravel?

Dependendo da versão pode usar o `request()->getParameter('id_cap')` para obter os dados deste parâmetro apenas, que esta vindo na rota